# push GCM message to all users

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am starting at GCM and need some help. I found some tutorials, and it looks like I need to collect user IDs first, to whom I would push a message. Is it possible to push messages to all users that installed my app? without collecting their IDs first?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to push messages to all users that installed my app? without collecting their IDs first?

No, sorry. You need to have registration IDs for sending messages.

Comment: am I understand right, the ID is just a "string", so I could randomly generate it and then store on my own server?

Comment: @user1908375: It is not "just a string". It is value given to you by the GCM system, when your app uses the registration APIs to register this app installation with GCM. This is covered [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-register) as part of [the overall instructions for writing a GCM-enabled Android app](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

Comment: Theoretically I don't see a reason that the self generated ids solution wont work. But note that thous GCMregID strings could grow up to 4k length, a huge number of options that you need to cover.

Comment: GCM is support for up to 1,000 recipients for a single message.